# Parse query always true

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform

Perhaps this is not the right place for this, but I am sure that many users here are familiar with Parse framework for iOS. Basically I am having issues with a query, all I want to do is check if a username already exists (they do so at login) except I need to do it in order to set up a relationship between the current user and another user. Currently my method is:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
[query whereKey:@"username" equalTo:username.text];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        NSLog(@"query returned with result");

        for (PFObject *object in objects) {
            NSLog(@"%@", object.objectId);
        }
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Nope");
    }
}];
```

`username` is just a string containing the word entered in plain text from  `UITextField`. But no matter what I put in, the query seems to go through and I get a message of success. I even tried iterating through the objects as shown in the for loop and I get nothing logged. What is going on here?

**EDIT**
Just for clarification, `username` is simply taken from a `IBOutlet UITextField *username` from the view controller which takes in the username from input. I have tested to make sure that it is being taken correctly. If I enter "foo", I can log the username.text and it will be "foo", however I have no registered users named "foo" so I do not understand why the query is returning without error.

Comment: And where's the `if statement` that determines if it prints out `success` or not? Please share everything relevant and what is `username`? Is it a `UITextView` or `NSString`?

Comment: I mentioned its plain text from a `UITextField`. The `if (!error)` is the statement that determines if it prints successfully. Please re-read the question.

Comment: So where is the code that puts the text from `UITextField` into `username`? Again please share everything.

Comment: Its in `IBOutlet UITextField *username;` in the ViewController interface declaration. I don't think it matters because I am successfully getting a string from the `UITextField` and it is matching exactly what I input because I tested it. I am only trying to post relevant code so as not to confuse anyone.

Comment: You can assume `username` = "foo" or any other string. But I do not have that string as a registered user in Parse. So therefore, it shouldn't be found.

Comment: Well if `username` is a `UITextField` it is not plain text is it? It is an object of `UITextField` so just passing `username` into  `[query whereKey:@"username" equalTo:username];` will be trying to compare whatever `whereKey:` returns against an object of `UITextField` not a string. To get the string from a `UITextField` you need to be doing `[username text]` or `username.text`.

Comment: Sorry about that Popeye, I manually typed that code so I left out the .text accidentally. I fixed it :)

Comment: Double check your code and where you have missed something edit your question to include it. Once you have done that we can start again. There is no point in us wasting our time when your not sharing everything.

Comment: Its all there. Checked.

Comment: **Is it?** you say you get a **message of success** where in your code does it print out **Success** I can't see anywhere it will print this out.

Comment: Its pretty obvious where the success message is printed. I even explained it in my comment to humour you. If your that dumb then just leave

Comment: If you're not willing to give the correct information or even read proof read your code when sharing what makes you think anyone will help you. You say it prints out **Success** but it doesn't it prints out **query returned with result** little things like this will make users think that you're not sharing everything like I've already stated. I still think you're not sharing everything, and I have just lost interest now in helping you and I am just going to point you http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182266/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users/182380#182380

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get message of success even there is no object found.

(Try log objects.count)

If so, you should check your spelling on Key Value or Query Value.

They are case-sensitive.